# How to get rid of the Title Bar without losing the ICS look?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-titlebar

I tried this which was readily available when googled:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

But when I apply it, it changes the overall theme back to pre-ice cream sandwich. What I mean by that is the `TextView`'s, `DatePicker`s etc. are Gingerbread themed, not the ICS themed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type this is the onCreate() method before setContentView():

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: well i have no experience in ICS, but i created a theme once in styles.xml and added the attribute
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>.

and added the theme in  the manifest

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I will look into that. I was trying to avoid putting it in the java code, but a single line isn't bad. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to: `theme.Holo.Light.NoTitlebar.`

Comment: Could you type it exactly how its suppose to look. Its not letting me

Comment: Sorry I'm not at home, but I'll tell you when I get home. But you can see the suggestions by typing alt+space. This will show you the right suggestions. I supposE "Theme" is written with a capital letter. I'll update you later :)

Comment: Someone eddited my answer. I suppose it should be right now. :)